# mcms 2002 on windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-7, visual-studio-2003

anyone managed to install mcms 2002 on windows 7 ?

i tried installing vs.net 2003 n also 2005(using registry trick), but still the setup program cant detect vs.net already install on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MCMS is no longer supported on Windows 7.

However, you can still use Visual Studio 2010 to build your MCMS projects. Copy the MCMS DLL's from the Server\Bin folder and add this to your Global Assembly Cache.